# Safety measures for a textarea input in HTML form, processed by PHP, while its content should be HTML (with div p and other tags)

Tags: html, forms, sanitization

I have an issue. I thought about form safety. I have a field that is a textarea. By default it's hidden and instead a rich text editor appears (CKEditor if it plays a role). What I want to do is:

1. allow iframes only from YouTube (as there may be guys posting tutorial with videos) but I don't want iframes from other probably harmful sources.
2. Out of that I won't allow images (as I have read there are security holes for these elements also).
3. My last and biggest concern about the safety is how to prevent SQL Injection as it is a field with rich content.

Homework:

1. I thought about creating a var (eg. $fake_input = $actual_input). After that, to count the times iframes and youtube links show up in the $actual_input with preg_match_all. Next, to strip $fake_input from every iframe and count youtube links. So after stripping the following equotation must be valid, otherwise there is iframe from another source. $fake_youtube_links = $actual_youtube_links - $actual_iframes
   So, lets say we have a youtube link out of iframe, 1 malicious iframe and a normal (Youtube one) iframe it has to be 1 = 1 - 2, which is not true, so error will show up.
2. I thought clearing from photos to use preg_replace.
3. For last part, that's the strategy I have thought about. Make a $fake_input as in step 1. Remove any code samples (that exist for illustrational purpose only). And then after cleaning the samples to check the rest of the input for MySQL reserved words/phrases such as DELETE, ALTER, TRUNCATE etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple htmlspecialcharacter()? Putting that before save your data in database and you won't have problem.

Comment: I just saw it (what's its functionality) and converts some "dangerous" chars to html entities. Sorry if I ask "silly" questions, but is this enough against SQL Injection? Even if so, what other dangers should I take care of?

Comment: In order to avoid sql injections use prepared statments. Other than that you should 'encode' any html using htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities().